What sort order does Rust's built-in cmp for &str use?
As I understood from this question, there are many ways to interpret the order of two strings.
Rust provides a default implementation for Ord for str, but I can't find the answer to these questions:

Does it sort character by character, or by raw byte value?
If it sorts by characters, which locale does it use?


https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/primitive.str.html#impl-Ord-for-str is not that hard to find.

Just read the source!
The documentation generated by RustDoc -- which is used for the officially hosted documentation, among others -- always include a link to the source:
impl Ord for str {
    #[inline]
    fn cmp(&self, other: &str) -> Ordering {
        self.as_bytes().cmp(other.as_bytes())
    }
}

The answer, thus, is that for equality & ordering, Rust considers a str as just a slice of bytes.

Which is equivalent to sorting as a sequence of Unicode scalar values / code points.

@starblue: I believe so yes, given the way UTF-8 prefixes work.
